# Get Nested Json data in to pandas data frame and perform data processing on it

Tags: python, json, dataframe, prometheus

I want to get the below Nested JSON into a Pandas dataframe with out repeating values. I have created a python script to get the data into dataframe. But I got stuck in removing repeating values from inner list.

> 

```
{
   "status" : "success",
   "data" : {
      "resultType" : "matrix",
      "result" : [
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "prometheus",
               "instance" : "localhost:9090"
            },
            "values" : [
               [ 1435781430.781, "1" ],
               [ 1435781445.781, "1" ],
               [ 1435781460.781, "1" ]
            ]
         },
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "node",
               "instance" : "localhost:9091"
            },
            "values" : [
               [ 1435781430.781, "0" ],
               [ 1435781445.781, "0" ],
               [ 1435781460.781, "1" ]
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is the Json File. since the values are repeating in the first value list I want to get only this value,

"[ 1435781430.781, "1" ]"

from the second list I want to get only theses two rows,

```
[ 1435781430.781, "0" ],
[ 1435781460.781, "1" ]
```

This is the python script I use. But it only gives first two rows,

```
import pandas as pd
import json

response = """
{
   "status" : "success",
   "data" : {
      "resultType" : "matrix",
      "result" : [
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "prometheus",
               "instance" : "localhost:9090"
            },
            "values" : [
               [ 1435781430.781, "1" ],
               [ 1435781445.781, "1" ],
               [ 1435781460.781, "1" ]
            ]
         },
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "node",
               "instance" : "localhost:9091"
            },
            "values" : [
               [ 1435781430.781, "0" ],
               [ 1435781445.781, "0" ],
               [ 1435781460.781, "1" ]
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
"""

data_1 = json.loads(response)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_1["data"]["result"])
df['status'] = data_1['status']
df['resultType'] = data_1['data']['resultType']
df['value'] = data_1
df = pd.concat([df['status'],df['resultType'], df.pop("metric").apply(pd.Series), df.pop("value").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

print(df)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data']['result'])
# Turn list items into separate rows
df = df.explode("values")
# There is still list items on "values" column, separate it into two columns, so we can use second value for finding duplicates.
df[['values', 'value1']] = df['values'].to_list()
# Drop duplicates, you might want to check if this is correct subset for dropping
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["metric.instance", "metric.job"  , "value1"])
```

Result

```
         values metric.__name__  metric.job metric.instance value1
0  1.435781e+09              up  prometheus  localhost:9090      1
1  1.435781e+09              up        node  localhost:9091      0
1  1.435781e+09              up        node  localhost:9091      1
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your code but it gives me only two values. I don't know why. I use the same code you have mentioned here

Comment: What values do you get?

Comment: The issue got sorted. Thanks a lot